# Django - permission denied

Tags: django, apache, http-status-code-403, permission-denied

I'm trying to setup Django (Django 1.9.6) on Apache (Apache 2.4.10) in my vps (ubuntu server 15.04).

I followed this guide: [HERE](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Unfortunately when I try to visit my website, the server return this error (403 Forbidden):`

```
[authz_core:error]  AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/user/proj/proj/wsgi.py
```

I searched everywhere for a solution but everything I tried didn't work.

this is my /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf file:

```
    Alias /static /home/user/proj/Gestione/static
    <Directory /home/user/proj/Gestione/static>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/user/proj/proj>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
        </Files>
    </Directory>
    WSGIDaemonProcess proj python-path=/home/user/proj:/home/user/.local/lib/python3.4/site-p$
    WSGIProcessGroup proj
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/proj/proj/wsgi.py
```

Then i found this code on /etc/apache2/apache2.conf, I don't know if this could create problems:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

This is my wsgy.py:

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "proj.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I'm NOT using virtualenv

Thanks for help

Comment: This looks like a permission error to me.

Comment: chmod o+x wsgy.py already done

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django apache configuration with WSGIDaemonProcess not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38284814/django-apache-configuration-with-wsgidaemonprocess-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

In Apache 2.4, you should use `Require all granted` instead of `Order deny,allow` and `Allow from all`.

It looks like you are using the old style in two places in `000-default.conf`. Try updating it to:

```
<Directory /home/user/proj/Gestione/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/user/proj/proj>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

Comment: `[wsgi:error] mod_wsgi (pid=9976): Target WSGI script /home/user/proj/proj/wsgi.py cannot be loaded as Python module.` now return this error with "500 internal server error"

Comment: @big can you update the question with what your apache logs say (guesses on potential issues include: permissions on the files (I normally put django stuff someplace apache can get to and make apache own the files) or a wsgi python2 vs python3 issue)

Comment: That's a separate issue. Please either update your question to include ` Require all granted` (like your tutorial says you should), and I'll delete this answer, or ask a new question. If there is a traceback in the logs, include the full traceback in the question.

Comment: @Foon updated question: [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37255292/django-500-internal-server-error-no-module-named-django)