# Django - 500 internal server error "no module named django"

Tags: python, django, apache, http-status-code-500

django return 500 internal server error (apache 2.4.10, ubuntu 15.04, django 1.9.6)

apache log:

```
[wsgi:warn] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.4.2.
[wsgi:warn] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.4.3.
[mpm_event:notice] AH00489: Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.3.0  Python/3.4.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[core:notice] [pid 9973:tid 140000454645632] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[wsgi:error] mod_wsgi (pid=9976): Target WSGI script '/home/user/KeyShare/KeyShare/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[wsgi:error] mod_wsgi (pid=9976): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/user/KeyShare/KeyShare/wsgi.py'.
[wsgi:error] traceback (most recent call last):
[wsgi:error] File "/home/user/KeyShare/KeyShare/wsgi.py", line 12, in  <module>
[wsgi:error] from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[wsgi:error] ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf file:

```
Alias /static /home/user/proj/Gestione/static
<Directory /home/user/proj/Gestione/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/user/proj/proj>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
WSGIDaemonProcess proj python-path=/home/user/proj:/home/user/.local/lib/python3.4/site-p$
WSGIProcessGroup proj
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/proj/proj/wsgi.py
```

wsgy.py:

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "proj.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I'm NOT using virtualenv

thanks for help

related question: [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37238192/django-permission-denied)

**EDIT:** I had installed django with non-root user, now I reinstall it as root user and It works. Thanks everyone

Comment: did u install django globally using `pip install django` ?

Comment: If you think you have already installed Django, how did you install it? If you used `pip`, did you use the pip in `/home/user/.local/lib/python3.4/`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django apache configuration with WSGIDaemonProcess not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38284814/django-apache-configuration-with-wsgidaemonprocess-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are missing django. This error is returned by wsgi not django. You can check using `pip freeze`. Make sure django is listed in the output of pip freeze. Else install django with pip using command

`pip install django`

`It is always recommended to use virtual environment` to avoid messing up with global dependencies. If working in a virtual environment does not create any problems for you, then go for virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

In my guess, adding path to wsgi.py may help:

```
import os
import sys
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

path = '/path/to/your/project'

if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```